# Rollback after Execute in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, sqlite, rails-activerecord

I am building a sandbox for an sqlite3 db in Rails so that people can query the data themselves. Right now I have it just calling execute like this:

`@results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(params[:query])`

In the case of destructive commands, I want to rollback this every time after I get my results. What is a good way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I got some for you:

> Active Record class **ActiveRecord::Base** has method called connection()
>   which returns valid connection to MySQL (or some other) database using
>   config/database.yml database settings.
>
> Return value of **connection()** method is an object of class MysqlAdpater
>   (or [some-other-database]Adapter). Here are some useful methods of
>   that object:
>
> - **execute** - executes SQL query. For "SELECT ..." query will return    Mysql::Result class (or other result-set class for your Ruby
>     database    interface).
> - **insert** - executes SQL query and returns last inserted id
> - **update, delete** - executes SQL query and returns number of affected rows
> - **begin_db_transaction** - executes SQL query 'BEGIN' (transaction    start)
> - **commit_db_transaction** - executes SQL query 'COMMIT' (confirm    transaction)
> - **rollback_db_transaction** - executes SQL query 'ROLLBACK'    (rollback transaction)
>
> There is also methods select_all and select_one, but we do not
>   recommend using it, because of inefficient implementation trying to
>   fetch all selected values to memory.

Check out this [Documentation](http://www.anyexample.com/webdev/rails/rails_and_sql_queries.xml).

Comment: This is some of the documentation I found on my own, but there doesn't seem to be a way I can find to rollback the query. After i run `execute` I want to rollback the code I just executed, or at least something to the same effect.